# my-weather-indicator report in syslog

Tags: gnome, syslog, my-weather-indicator

Running Ubuntu 16.04...  My-weather indicator places the weather forecast data in the syslog every time it checks the weather.  It works OK  ... but I am wondering if this is normal and why it is doing this... previous versions of Ubuntu did not have this "feature"

```
Jun  1 08:03:19 jonathan-asus64 gnome-session[1618]: y': None,
'maxwind': None, 'wind_icon': None, 'condition_image':
'mwig-clear.png', 'condition': 'fair'}], 'current_conditions':
{'feels_like': '67', 'temperature': '67', 'heat_index': 0,
'sunrise_time_utc': '09:44', 'visibility': '14 mi', 'sunset_time_utc':
'00:27', 'rawOffset': -4.0, 'sunrise': '05: 44 AM', 'precip_today':
None, 'sunset_time': '20:27', 'humidity': '92.0 %', 'dew_point': '65',
'condition_text': 'Partly cloudy', 'dusk_time': '20:58',
'solarradiation': None, 'cloudiness': 'N/A', 'moon_phase': 'Waning
Crescent', 'dusk': '08: 58 PM', 'sunrise_time': '05:44', 'pressure':
'29.8 inches of mercury', 'condition_icon_dark':
'mwid-partly-cloudy-night.png', 'wind_condition': '7 mph (W)',
'condition_image': 'mwig-partly-cloudy-night.png',
[Rest of weather log not shown]
```

The full log is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16900496/).

Comment: OK I figured it out ... when they fixed this error ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1568774 ) they waited for the error message and then created an exception which allowed it to get the weather but also created a lengthy error message each time ... I just followed the instruction to remove the s in https in query.yahooapis.com  in  /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/wyahooapi.py (line 108). and that solved the issue.  no more syslog full of weather.

Comment: That sounds like an answer. Please post it as one. :)

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out! When they fixed this [error](http://bugs.launchpad.net/my-weather-indicator/+bug/1568774) they waited for the error message and then created an exception which allowed it to get the weather but also created a lengthy error message each time.

I just followed the instruction to remove the `s` in `https` in `query.yahooapis.com` in `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/wyahooapi‌​.py` (line 108) and that solved the issue.

No more `syslog` full of weather.